# Getting data from reducer into FlatList component

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, reducers

My code is working but I don't understand how "library" and library.id works in the keyExtractor. How library.id get id of the items from "libraries" reducer?

And also "library" in renderItem(library) and "library"  in keyExtractor are same?

I would appreciate if anybody can shortly explain this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import ListItem from './ListItem';

class LibraryList extends Component {
  renderItem(library) {
    return <ListItem library={library} />;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={this.props.libraries}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
        keyExtractor={library => library.id}
      />
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { libraries: state.libraries };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LibraryList);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`library` (can be named anything) in your renderItem is coming from your
    data={this.props.libraries}

```
renderItem(library) {
  return <ListItem library={library} />;
}
```

`this.props.libraries` is coming from redux

```
- the key name `libraries` can be named anything other than `libraries`
- state.libraries is coming from your redux reducer (check your root reducer)

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { libraries: state.libraries };
};
```

this is extracting the key id from your data which is coming from `data={this.props.libraries}`

```
keyExtractor={library => library.id}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Everything is clear except first part. You say i can call renderItem(anything), so how does it know anything or library is coming from data=this.props.libraries. Where is the connection?

Comment: it's in react FlatList documentation, https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#renderitem